# What is the difference between these two XML structures ?

Tags: xml

Here are the two ways for data structures i can think of with XML :

```
1) 
<root>
<color value1="red" value2="green" ></color> 
</root> 


2) 
<root>
<color>
<value1> red </value1>
<value2> green </value2> 
</color>
</root>
```

Which one is better ? Why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just an fyi: Your second XML example is missing the final `</root>` closing tag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

That will clear up everything for you

Answer (score 1):

You know, the first form suffer from the limitation that is not possible to have two attributes of an element with the same name. The second one not (it should be used in cases like yours) and the XML tree can become

```
<root>
    <color>
        <value>red</value>
        <value>green</value> 
    </color>
</root>
```

or

```
<root>
    <color>
        <token_less_generic_than_value>red</token_less_generic_than_value>
        <token_less_generic_than_value>green</token_less_generic_than_value> 
    </color>
</root>
```

or even

```
<root>
    <color>
        <red/>
        <green/> 
    </color>
</root>
```

it is just a matter of personal taste. The first form, on the other hand feels wrong to me as you have to change the names of attributes just for having more than one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer 1, since it is lesser code while parsing the xml. XML is the most famous context sensitive language, you should code it in a way that is "understandable" for the person coding it. If I had simple data to represent, I would code using 1. If I think it will become complex, I will careful about what I choose. And yes, please read up w3schools, the question you asked is way to basic.